# Jump to html anchor when "restoring window" to original size, no JS?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm writing a one-page exercise site of the following simplified structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="paving">
        <a href="#list">Change layout to list</a>
    </section>
    <section id="list">
        <a href="#paving">Change layout to paving</a>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

it has two `<section>`'s in it, each styled

```
section {
    height: 90vh;
    margin-bottom: 10vh;
}
```

Relevant body settings include

```
body {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 200vh;
}
```

so at any given moment only one of two sections is shown fully, other fully hidden. The only way to move between these two blocks is to use two links-anchors: have a look at screen 1, red button in the corner takes you to the second section with identical button (these 2 buttons are just anchors to each other): [image: first section]

But the trouble starts when I try to resize the window to a smaller size, then click whichever button I can see right now, and THEN hitting "restore window" button in my browser.
[image: wrecked position after restore] As you can see, browser restores it to an arbitrary position of height, while I want to achieve behaviour where browser would restore it to any of the anchors (So that any of the sections would "stick" to the top again, like on the screenshot number 1).

Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

I do not think specifying the browser is necessary, this has been reproduced in multiple, so I guess this is just a peculiarity of the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `scroll-snap-type` and `scroll-snap-align` to force the scrolling to snap to each `section`:

```css
section {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  height: 90vh;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="paving">
  <a href="#list">Change layout to list</a>
</section>
<section id="list">
  <a href="#paving">Change layout to paving</a>
</section>
```

[Here's](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/) an in-depth article on it.

Browser support seems good, except, no IE support.